# SQL server full text search with wildcard in search parameter

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a table with a **full text index** on it and I am looking for rows that contain a string like `"p.G213*"` but SQL server is treating the star like a wildcard, when I am trying to search for the EXACT string `"p.G213*"`.

Is there any way to escape the star character in contains(...) ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Search for a word with a prefix (Prefix Term)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16#Prefix_Term) doc, you should achieve it by not using the double quotation marks:

> All text that matches the text specified before the asterisk (*) is
> returned. If the text and asterisk are not delimited by double
> quotation marks, as in `CONTAINS (DESCRIPTION, 'top*')`, full-text
> search does not consider the asterisk to be a wildcard..

Therefore, just change `"p.G213*"` for `'p.G213*'`.